# Keras LSTM Paradigm

Tags: python, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have a single time series that has multiple input features and a single output (classification). I would like to create a model that would predict the output at every step.

My data looks like this:

x: [[0.4, 0.8, -1], [1, 1.6, -0.2], ....]

y: [[1], [0], ...]

So when given a single feature vector, I would like my model to output 0 or 1. The feature vector is not a sequence of any kind, as this is just a straight-forward time series.

I have the following questions:

1. Since Keras requires data to be formatted in `(batch_size, time_steps, num_features)` and I have fixed `num_features = 3`, what should I put for `batch_size` and `time_steps`?
2. What do I put for the value of `stateful`? Since my data is in a specific order in that the first event in my list came first, followed by the second and third etc., I'm assuming I put `stateful = True`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but your batch_size could be set automatically, time_steps is equal to number of feature sets so for [[0.4, 0.8, -1]] its 1 for [[0.4, 0.8, -1],[1, 1.6, -0.2]] its 2 etc. Try to reshape your data to (shape[0],3).

Answer (score 0):

If you are just starting to train LSTM models, I recommend using `stateful=False`. Once you are more comfortable with input shapes and how LSTM works, you can consider using `stateful=True`. You can read more about it [here](http://philipperemy.github.io/keras-stateful-lstm/).

With that being said, Keras requires the data to be formatted as `(num_samples, time_stepss, num_features)`. `batch_size` is a parameter you set when you want to fit your model. Indeed, both `batch_size` and `time_steps` are hyperparameters that you may tweek and see which one results in better performance. So, first decide on the `time_steps` and if you want samples to have overlaps or not.

For example, you may decide to create samples with `time_steps=4` and 2 time_steps overlapping between each sample:

x[0], x[1], x[2], x[3] -> y[0], y[1], y[2], y[3]

x[2], x[3], x[4], x[5] -> y[2], y[3], y[4], y[5]

x[4], x[5], x[6], x[7] -> y[4], y[5], y[6], y[7]

...

With `time_steps` and overlap fixed, you would get a total `num_samples`. Then you can feed this data into `model.fit()` with a `batch_size` of like 32, 64, and so on.

If you want to avoid writing code to reshape your data, you can use Keras's [TimeseriesGenerator](https://keras.io/preprocessing/sequence/). Note that length is used for `time_steps` and `stride` determines the overlap.